# I have two models and they are connected through ForiegnKey in my Django Project

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

#Models.py

```
     class Appname(models.Model):

       name=models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False,null=False)

       def __str__(self):
           return self.name
class placement(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='placeid', null=True, default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    name=models.ForeignKey(Appname,related_name='appname',null=True,default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE,editable=False)
    ad_space=models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False,null=False)
    PID_TYPE = (
        ('FN','FORMAT_NATIVE'),
        ('FNB','FORMAT_NATIVE_BANNER'),
        ('FI','FORMAT_INTERSTITIAL'),
        ('FB','FORMAT_BANNER'),
        ('FMR','FORMAT_MEDIUM,RECT'),
        ('FRV','FORMAT_REWARDED_VIDEO'),
        )

       format = models.CharField(max_length=3,choices = PID_TYPE,default = 'FN',blank=False, null=False)
       pid=models.CharField( max_length=50,default='',blank=False, null=False)
       cpm=models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False, null=False)
       ADS_TYPE=(
       ('FB','FACEBOOK'),
       ('G','GOOGLE'),
       )         source=models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=ADS_TYPE,default='FB',blank=False, null=False)
      comments=models.TextField(default='',blank=False, null=False)
      objects=models.Manager()


      def __str__(self):
         return self.ad_space

      def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse("dashapp:view")
```

## Here is the Ques.

I  save my first model through form using generic view now i have used ForeignKey in my 2nd model . I want  that when i fill my second Form the name variable gets autofill with the first model value . can i do that??

Comment: Note: `related_name='appname'` is wrong for the `name` field on `placement`. Because this should be the name of the reverse relationship, i.e. if you have an `Appname` object `a`, how to access all the `placement` objects. Probably you want `related_name="placements"` (note plural) so you can then access `a.placements`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use initial argument of the Form 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial

```
name = Appname.objects.get(name='name')
form = SecondForm(initial={'name': name})
```